# Swift 3.0 In-App

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement In-App purchases in my app, can you tell me whats wrong with my code, I'm getting this error

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class PatronageViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    var productIDs: NSSet = []
    var productsArray: Array<SKProduct?> = []
       var product: SKProduct?
    var transactionInProgress = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        productIDs = NSSet(objects: "com.app.appname.12months","com.app.appname.3months","com.app.appname.6months")

        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)

        requestProductInfo()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func requestProductInfo()
    {
        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
        {
           let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: (productIDs as! Set<String>))

            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }
        else
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "In-App Purchases Not Enabled", message: "Please enable In App Purchase in Settings", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { alertAction in
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
                if url != nil
                {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url! as URL)
                }

            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { alertAction in
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse)
    {
        var products = response.products

        if (products.count != 0) {
            for i in 0 ..< products.count
            {
                self.product = products[i] as SKProduct
                self.productsArray.append(product!)
                print(product)

            }
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Ups", message: "Something went wrong!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
            print("No products found")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func add3MonthsAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if !(transactionInProgress)
        {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: self.productsArray[1]! as SKProduct)
             print(payment.productIdentifier)
            print(productsArray[1])
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
            self.transactionInProgress = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func add6MonthsAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if !(transactionInProgress)
        {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: self.productsArray[2]! as SKProduct)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
            self.transactionInProgress = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func add12MonthsAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if !(transactionInProgress)
        {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: self.productsArray[0]! as SKProduct)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
            self.transactionInProgress = true
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
    {
        for transaction in transactions 
        {
            switch transaction.transactionState
            {
                case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchasing:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                    transactionInProgress = false

                    if transaction.payment.productIdentifier == "com.app.appname.12months"
                    {
                        // Unlock Feature
                        //unlockAM()
                        print("12months")
                    }
                    else if transaction.payment.productIdentifier == "com.app.appname.3months"
                    {
                        //unlockBMW()
                        print("3months")
                    }
                    else if transaction.payment.productIdentifier == "com.app.appname.6months"
                    {
                        //unlockMCL()
                        print("6months")
                    }

                case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionInProgress = false

                default:
                    print(transaction.transactionState.rawValue)
            }
        }
    }

    func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        print("There was an error");
    }

    @IBAction func restorePurchases(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("Transactions Restored")

        for transaction:SKPaymentTransaction in queue.transactions {
            if transaction.payment.productIdentifier == "com.app.appname.12months"
            {
                // black
               // unlockAM()
                print("12months")
            }
            else if transaction.payment.productIdentifier == "com.app.appname.3months"
            {
                //pink
               // unlockBMW()
                print("3months")
            }
            else if transaction.payment.productIdentifier == "com.app.appname.6months"
            {
                //red
               // unlockMCL()
                print("6months")
            }
        }

        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "Your purchase(s) were restored.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
    }

    @IBAction func dismissViewController(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error? What's the complete error message?

Comment: When I press on a button to buy the feature everything is fine but I don't get the alert view, instead of that I get this error 

Transaction Approved
Product Identifier: com.app.myapp.3months
`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

I think I've messed up here    `case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchasing:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)`

Comment: ` *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot finish a purchasing transaction'
*** First throw call stack:`

Comment: @rmaddy instead of purchasing I had to use purchased and instead of real apple account I had to use a sandbox user.. thanks